# mysql WHERE and LAST

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to get from base a last record where `code = variable` and `complete = 0`.

I use this SQL:

```
SELECT email, date FROM users_recovery WHERE restore_key = '" . $code . "' AND complete = '0'
```

For example DB:

```
email - code - complete - date
test@email - code1 - 0 - 1111111
test@email - code2 - 0 - 2222222
```

If variable `$code` will be one of values in DB, then query will perfectly work, but I also  need to check is it the last record with this **email** or not, but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT b.email, b.date, b.complete, b.code
FROM   (SELECT email, 
               Max(date) AS date 
        FROM   users_recovery 
        GROUP  BY email
        WHERE  code = variable
               AND complete = 0) a 
       JOIN users_recovery b 
         ON b.email = a.email 
            AND b.date = a.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT` to limit the results to the last record (e.e. ORDER BY most recent date):

```
SELECT 
    email, 
    date 
FROM 
    users_recovery 
WHERE 
    restore_key = '" . $code . "' 
AND complete = '0'
ORDER BY 
    date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It will not work, because restore_key is unique value, but I need to check last record by email.

Answer (score 0):

Use INNER JOIN with MAX()

```
SELECT
  email,
  date
FROM users_recovery AS ur
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
        MAX(DAte) AS date
          FROM users_recovery) AS url
    ON url.date = ur.date
WHERE restore_key = '" . $code . "'
    AND complete = '0'
```